# Custom emoticon keyboard IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, keyboard, xcode6

I am currently in the process of building a custom keyboard for IOS devices and wanted to add a custom EMOJI keyboard as well. I have a sheet of custom emoticons already created and do not want the user to have to copy and paste into their message like on the Ikea Emoticon keyboard. Is it possible to have a clone of apples keyboard functionality but with my own emoticons?

Comment: can you post what you've tried so far and where you failed ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have something similar like below (emoticon icon)

[image]

You can make a slideout `UIView` with a bunch of your custom emojis using `UICollectionView`. If the user taps on an emoji it would insert your own [Unicode Emoji Text](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) (just example).

You will have to make your own if statements if the text contains emoji unicode to make the emojis appear in your text.

This is how I understand it, I might be wrong, if so, please correct me. :)